# Help with proving or disproving

Tags: polynomials

True or false?

If $\frac{a_0}{1}+\frac{a_1}{2}+\ldots+\frac{a_n}{n+1}=0$ then there is $x\in(0,1)$ that solves $a_0+a_1 x +\ldots +a_n x^n =0$.

Comment: The given equation is the integral of the polynomial from $0$ to $1$. Which means the area under the polynomial from $0$ to $1$ is $0$.

Answer (score 0):

True. Given $p(x)=a_0+a_1 x+\ldots +a_n x^n$, we know that:
$$\int_{0}^{1}p(x)\,dx =0,$$
and since $p(x)$ is a continuous function, that may happen only if $p(x)$ has some zero in $(0,1)$ by the [mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#First_Mean_Value_Theorem_for_Definite_Integrals).